# react-admin fetchUtils doesn't get headers

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I was trying to follow this tutorial https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#connecting-to-a-real-api

my server is a simple python flask as endpoint server, as the tutorial said, i need set `x-total-count` into header, so i do it in my flask app like:

```
@posts.get("/posts")
def all():
    print("headers-->", request.headers)

    payload = [
        {
            "userId": 10,
            "id": 100,
            "title": "at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum",
            "body": "cupiditate quo est a modi nesciunt soluta\nipsa voluptas error itaque dicta in\nautem qui minus magnam et distinctio eum\naccusamus ratione error aut",
            "views": 1999,
            "published_at": "12/10/2022"
        }

    ]
    # X-Total-Count 
    headers = {"X-Total-Count": "20", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "x-total-count"}
    response = jsonify(payload)
    return response, HTTP_200_OK, headers
```

and after i do curl or refresh my browser, i can see the headers has been sent to client,

[image]

and my `reactjs` code like below:

```
import { fetchUtils } from "react-admin";
import { stringify} from "query-string";

const apiUrl = "http://192.168.31.40:5001/posts"
// const apiUrl ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
// const httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;

const authToken="123123";

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json', "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "X-Total-Count"});
    }
  
    options.headers.set('Authorization', authToken);
    // options.headers.set(Access-Control-Expose-Headers, "*");
    // Access-Control-Expose-Headers
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(apiUrl, options)
};

export default {
    // 获取列表
    getList: async (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
            range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
            filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        const {status, headers, body, json } = await httpClient(url);

        headers.set("a", "123")
        console.log("status --->", status)
        console.log("headers --->", headers)
        console.log("body --->", body)
        return ({
            data: json,
            total: 1,//parseInt(headers.get('x-total-count')),
        });
    },
    getOne: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`).then(({ json }) => ({
            data: json,
        })),

    getMany: async (resource, params) => {
        const query = {
            filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids }),
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        const { json } = await httpClient(url);
        return ({ data: json });
    },

    getManyReference: async (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
            range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
            filter: JSON.stringify({
                ...params.filter,
                [params.target]: params.id,
            }),
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

        const { headers, json } = await httpClient(url);
        return ({
            data: json,
            total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
        });
    },

    update: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json })),

    updateMany: async (resource, params) => {
        const query = {
            filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids}),
        };
        const { json } = await httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        });
        return ({ data: json });
    },

    create: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({
            data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
        })),

    delete: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json })),

    deleteMany: async (resource, params) => {
        const query = {
            filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids}),
        };
        const { json } = await httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        });
        return ({ data: json });
    }
};
```

I can't see the `headers` in browser console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the browser inspector the headers look like they are empty because it's an iterator, not an object. You can iterate through the response headers like so:

```
for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]);
}
```

Check out this blogpost for more information: https://stevemiller.dev/2019/getting-response-headers-with-javascript-fetch/

I also had to explicitly expose my custom header in my web api backend for it to work. This might also be a reason why the response header is not showing up.